# Appending to one list in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

In my code my return value is appended to the list. What would be the way to append all the items to a single list? Right now, every stack creates a list and returns the list.

```
def palindrome_partition(string):
  if len(string) <=2:
    rev = string[::-1]
    if string == rev:
        return string
    else:
        return

  pal = []
  b = string[1:-1]
  if len(b) <=1:
    return
  a = b[::-1]
  res = palindrome_partition(b)
  if res is not None:
    pal.append(res)
  if a == b:
    pal.append(b)
  return pal
```

Result is `[[[],]]`
Desired result `[ , , ]`

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Desired result : [ , , ]

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, replace

```
pal.append(res)
```

with

```
pal += res
```

Comment: when you append res, you are appending a list to a list each time.